# Show Profile Image in Nav bar using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to show user image in navbar top section like Username "Image" just like in this site or any other.

This is what i try.

**View**

```
 <li class="">
                    <a href="#" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profileimages/<?php if (isset($_SESSION['Prof']))
                        {
                            echo $_SESSION['Prof'];
                        }?>" alt=""><?php echo $admin;?>
                        <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu pull-right">
                        <li><a href="Profile"> Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Profile_Setting"> Setting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

I am putting the image in session in login model,

**Model**

```
public function login_admin($username,$password)
    {
        $query=$this->db->where(['Username'=>$username,'Password'=>$password])->get('dc_admin');
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $q=$row->Profile_Picture;
                $_SESSION['Prof']=$q;
            }

            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$username);
            redirect('Master/Users');
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('Master');
        }

    }
```

I am new in CI and try to learn, please tell what i can do here to get image, i am able to get the logged IN username but not the image.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show how you save the name of an image in your database? Reason nothing will work is since we have no idea if you save the entire path of a file or simply the name of the file.

Comment: Can you also confirm the images are on the server at all?

Comment: i am saving the image name in DB. and the images are available on the server, because same thing is working for my blog section etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just make a simple change in my code, and follow the session idea by the above Answers. The below code fixed my issue.

```
 public function login_admin($username,$password)
{
    $query=$this->db->where(['Username'=>$username,'Password'=>$password])->get('dc_admin');
    //this is for single record

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        $rw = $query->row();
        $q = $rw->Profile_Image;
        $this->session->set_userdata('prfimg', $q);
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$username);
        redirect('Master/Users');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('Master');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## MODEL

### **Step One**

Get the result from your query

```
function getUserDetails($user_id){
 $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
 $query = $this->db->get('tbl_user');

 return $query->row();
}
```

### **Step Two**

As @cssBlaster21895 said, insert the profile picture inside your session

```
$user_details = $this->M_Model->getUserDetails($user_id);
if($user_details){
 $this->session->set_userdata('profile_picture', $user_details->profile);
}

// Load your view
```

**Note** This has to be within the controller

### Step Three

Add the image to your navbar

```
<img src = "<?php if($this->session->userdata('profile_picture')) { echo $this->session->userdata(''profile_picture); } ?>" />
```

**Note** Something to note is, you would set the session when the user logs in then add the image to your navbar in your template.

Hope this helps